# How to get data from a list Json with python

Tags: python, json

I am new to python and have tried to get data from a python json document , what I try to do is pass the information to python and json from python print a pdf with a table style.
My code in json is

```
[
    {
        "files": 0, 
        "data": [
            {"name": "RFC", "value": "XXXXXXX", "attId": 01}, 
            {"name": "NOMBRE", "value": "JOSE", "attId": 02}, 
            {"name": "APELLIDO PATERNO", "value": "MONTIEL", "attId": 03}, 
            {"name": "APELLIDO MATERNO", "value": "MENDOZA", "attId": 04}, 
            {"name": "FECHA NACIMIENTO", "value": "1989-02-04", "attId": 05}
        ], 
        "dirId": 1, 
        "docId": 4, 
        "structure": {
            "name": "personales", 
            "folioId": 22
        }
    }, 
    {
        "files": 0, 
        "data": [
            {"name": "CALLE", "value": "AMOR", "attId": 06}, 
            {"name": "No. EXTERIOR", "value": "4", "attId": 07}, 
            {"name": "No. INTERIOR", "value": "2", "attId": 08}, 
            {"name": "C.P.", "value": "55060", "attId": 09}, 
            {"name": "ENTIDAD", "value": "ESTADO DE MEXICO", "attId": 10}, 
            {"name": "MUNICIPIO", "value": "ECATEPEC", "attId": 11}, 
            {"name": "COLONIA", "value": "INDUSTRIAL", "attId": 12}
            ], 
        "dirId": 1, 
        "docId": 4, 
        "structure": {
            "name": "direccion", 
            "folioId": 22
        }
    }
]
```

and in python i tip the next code

```
import json
f= open(prueba.json)
prueba = json.load(f)
prueba
```

print correctly content of json,but my idea is get only for example:

```
Nombre,Jose
```

and then use the parameters to build the table in pdf

I have tried the following

```
 import json
 json_data = []
 with open('prueba.json') as json_file:
     json_data = json.load(json_file)
 for key, value in json_data.iteritems():
   print key; 
   for item in value: 
      print item 
      for key, value in json_data.iteritems(): 
         print key; 
         for item in value: 
            print item
```

But i have the next error:

```
    AttributeError : 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

I 'm trying to do something for them but I must get each data of json

Comment: "get only for example". Please describe in more detail which data you want to extract from the JSON file and how you want to output this data. Please [edit] your question and include a small sample of how the output is supposed to look like.

Comment: what is `json_data`?

Comment: That's because `json_data` is a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: Your JSON code is invalid. When I try to `json.load(json_file)` I get a `ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 5 column 59 (char 104)`.

Comment: The problem with your JSON code is that whole numbers can't have a leading zero — like the `"attId"`s do in your example — see the syntax diagram of [**number**](http://www.json.org/) at json.org.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
json_data = [] # your list with json objects (dicts)

with open('prueba.json') as json_file:
   json_data = json.load(json_file)

for item in json_data:
    for data_item in item['data']:
        print data_item['name'], data_item['value']
```

Comment: I have de next error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prueba.py", line 5, in <module>
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 368, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 53 column 1 - line 53 column 2 (char 1736 - 1737)

Comment: Do you load json file as shown as in your post? If so - can you provide you json file? You can post it's content (or part of it) to Pastebin, for example

Comment: On the second thought - your json is invalid. You have values like `06` instead of `6`. You have to fix this first. You can validate your json using http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Yes, because of the leading zeros in the numbers it's invalid. If a number starts with 0, it will be interpreted as [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal), or base 8. Octal just uses digits from 0 to 7. So, it fails at ```08``` and ```09```. But how can we fix it? ...

Comment: another question i have work with reportlab but i don´t know as i can load this information in a table(PDF)

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
for key, value in json_data.iteritems():
    print key
    if isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
        for item in value: 
            print item
    if isinstance(value, (dict)):
        for value_key,value_value in value.iteritems(): 
            print value_key,str(value_value)
```

Can be improved to manage more types and can be made recursive.

Comment: I get de same error   AttributeError : 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'