# Python map variables from list

Tags: python, json

I come to `python` from `js`. I have list like:

```
[{_id: '1', data: {}}, {_id: '2', data: {}}]
```

my goal is to get list of `_id`'s like `[1, 2]`

Comment: Google Python list comprehension

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get data from a list Json with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510352/how-to-get-data-from-a-list-json-with-python)

Comment: Yes, it is what I need

Answer (score 4):

As it's javascript object, not a json, you need 3rd party library like [demjson](https://github.com/dmeranda/demjson) to convert it to json.

```
In [70]: import demjson

In [71]: demjson.decode("[{_id: '1', data: {}}, {_id: '2', data: {}}]")
Out[71]: [{'_id': '1', 'data': {}}, {'_id': '2', 'data': {}}]

In [72]: converted_json = demjson.decode("[{_id: '1', data: {}}, {_id: '2', data: {}}]")

In [74]: [int(i["_id"]) for i in converted_json]
Out[74]: [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple list comprehension -

```
j = [{'_id': '1', 'data': {}}, {'_id': '2', 'data': {}}]

#One liner
[int(i.get('_id')) for i in j]
```

```
[1,2]
```