# how can i get value from json turned into list?

Tags: python, json, list, web, scroll

I scraped the list on the Internet and received list the following form.
I want to get the stock_code of the element with corp_code 1, but how should i code it with python?

list goes on like below

```
list = [{
    'status': '000', 
    'message': 'normal', 
    'list': [
        {'rcept_no': '20220322000596', 'reprt_code': '11011', 'bsns_year': '2021', 'corp_code': '1', 'stock_code': '950100'},
        {'rcept_no': '20220322000596', 'reprt_code': '11011', 'bsns_year': '2021', 'corp_code': '2', 'stock_code': '950111'},
        {'rcept_no': '20220322000596', 'reprt_code': '11011', 'bsns_year': '2021', 'corp_code': '3', 'stock_code': '950122'}
    ]
]
```

Comment: Similar question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30510527/9773203

Comment: Loop through `list[0]['list']`, looking for the `corp_code` you want.

Comment: BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name. It's the name of a built-in function.